# Cannot disable cipher suite "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" in IIS / Windows Server 2022

Tags: ssl, iis, cipher, windows-server-2022

I am using this command in Windows Server 2022, latest updates:

Disable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"

It completes without error.  I then tried restarting IIS (and also the server).

But this cipher suite still shows up in SSL Labs.  Is this suite part of the suite named "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"?  Is that why it can't be turned off?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 are different ciphers

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks - so then how can I disable "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"?